# how to run my main extension function on all tabs when I click a button?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a function to parse some tags in websites by using Chrome extension. Now it works only on the current tab. I want to parse DOM(outerHTML) of all other tabs in current Chrome window. I want to apply my function to other tabs simultaneusly when I click button in my extension popup. How can I run it? And how can I get DOM (document.outerHTML) of other tabs by tabId?

I have tried `chrome.scripting.executeScript(tabId, {...})` but I could not get it. I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

How can I execute certain function in my `content.js` file in `background.js` if I need to iterate through all tabs and execute file `content.js`? In `chrome.scripting.executeScript(tabId, file: [content.js])` it is running the whole file, but I need to run certain function in `content.js`?

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.query({url: `'*://*/*'`}) to get all tabs and then call executeScript on each one.

Comment: @wOxxOm should I write this in background.js or content_script.js or in popup.js?